# import a vendor file into a webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, reference, vendor

I have project based on a [chrome extension webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/samuelsimoes/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate). Now I want to use the [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/) library in one of my js-files. I tried two ways to import/reference the library file but none of them worked:

1.
installed interact.js with npm. Now I have the node module installed but don't know how to import the functionality into my ecmascript 6 file. I've tried:

```
import * as interact from "interact";
import "module-name";
```

2.
Saved the interact.min.js in an vendor folder into my src directory and referenced it directly into my html file. The problem here is, that the vendor folder didn't get copied into the build folder by webpack. This has the effect, that the html file doesn't find the interact.min.js file.

```
<script src="js/vendor/interact.min.js"></script>
```

How can I import and use the library?

Comment: import in the entrypoint. If you put in the html webpack wont know about it.

Comment: @MatheusSilva Thanks for your answer! what exactly do you mean with entrypoint?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry